# How incorporate string comparison with count-If in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an `If` condition that checks id number, start date and end date.  To this if condition I want to add a string comparison that checks True or False values in two different columns.  I was wondering I could make another `application.worksheetfunction.countif` for this?

```
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(completed.Range(COLUMN_A_IN_COMPLETE & iTotRecsD), Val2) > 0 _
    And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(completed.Range(COLUMN_B_IN_COMPLETE & iTotRecsB), Val1) > 0 _
    And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(completed.Range(COLUMN_C_IN_COMPLETE & iTotRecsE), Val3) > 0 _
    And (StrComp(Val4, Val5) = 0) Then
```

This code is just running even if values are exactly the same.

Edit* 
Val4 is worksheet2.Cells(row 2, column4)
Val5 is worksheet1.Cells(row 2, column4)

```
And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(completed.Range(COLUMN_D_IN_COMPLETE & iTotRecsF), Val4) > 0 Then
```

Doesn't seem to work well for string comparison, I wonder why?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand the question, however - "This code is just running even if the values are exactly the same"... If i'm just focusing on the line (StrComp(Val4, Val5) = 0), it seems like you want the two values to be the same right? StrComp will return 0 when the string values are equal, not different

Comment: Yes, this If condition checks four different columns (Int, date x 2, string).  If all the data is exactly the same nothing should happen.

Comment: Can you [edit] to explain exactly what `Val4` and `Val5` are supposed to be?

Comment: Is it possible to use count if rather than string compare?

Comment: Is `Range(COLUMN_A_IN_COMPLETE & iTotRecsD)` evaluating only one cell or a range of cells?

Comment: I just wanted to check with the above comment if your variable "COLUMN_A_IN_COMPLETE" was a single cell like "A" or if it was a range like "A1:A" to make sure you're using the formula correctly... but you probably are, so COUNTIF should still work on a range with strings. If it's not behaving properly it may be related to your data.. for example leading or trailing spaces will cause it not to match - "test " will not match with "test". Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple countIf, a single countIf's does the job.

```
    If (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(completed.Range(COLUMN_A_IN_COMPLETE & iTotRecsD), Val2, _
        completed.Range(COLUMN_B_IN_COMPLETE & iTotRecsB), Val1, _
        completed.Range(COLUMN_C_IN_COMPLETE & iTotRecsE), Val3, _
        completed.Range(COLUMN_D_IN_COMPLETE & iTotRecsF), Val4)) > 0 Then
```

It works now. :)